# How to give single quotes in SQL Query using yii frameowrk?

Tags: mysql, sql, yii

I'm trying to execute following SQL query using YII frameowrk

Query= **select * from table where name='Bachelor''s degree'**

By executing the above query I'm getting empty results. But I have content in tables.

From my perspective I think Yii framework not accepts query with single quotes in its contents.

So could you please suggest some other idea to resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try query with parameter.

```
$name = "Bachelor's degree";
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select()
    ->from('table_name')
    ->where('name = :name', array(':name' => "{$name}"))
    ->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

In YII way, bind your value to the statement.

```
    $name = "Bachelor's degree";
    $command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
    $command->select('table_column1,table_column2,table_column3');
    $command->from('table');
    $command->where('name=:name', array(':name'=>$name));
    echo $command->queryAll();
```